# How to make variables auto-complete in Notepad++?

Tags: php, notepad++

How do I make variables auto-complete in Notepad++? Many editors have it.

---

I'm working on a program scan file. For every string that begins with a `$` character, as soon as I type `$`, it would show me a drop down list of all variables I have used so far.

This is very useful where there are `long_descriptive_variables` in code, and I think it is a better way of programming than doing it like `$a`, `$b`, `$c`, but without autocompletion there is more room for error when typing these variables.

Comment: can I suggest to use netbeans for php? it's free and very useful with auto-completition for vars, functions , if statement ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://cybernetnews.com/notepad-50-can-auto-complete-code/):

> This feature is disabled by default, but a quick trip to the Preferences will get you using the new auto-complete feature in no time at all. Go to Settings -> Preferences, and switch to the Backup/Auto-competion tab. At the bottom of that screen you’ll see where you can enable auto-completion, and you can optionally turn on the “show function parameters” feature as well. What’s that do? Here’s an example of me using a PHP function, and you’ll notice that it gives me a friendly reminder of the parameters the function takes:

Keep in mind this is only supported in Notepad++ 5.0 or later...

Answer (score 6):

You can use word completion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to autocomplete any word in your document, including your functions, definitions, vars, et cetera.

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ (v5.5) cannot auto-complete variables or functions you have declared, just language function names and possibly their arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Notepad++ do auto complete through following steps:

```
Settings > Preferences > Backup/Auto-Completion
```

Under the section "`Auto-Completion"`, you can change the settings.

```
Enable auto-completion on each input > Word Completion
```

Through this, we get variables autocompleted.